# how to send "Secure SMS" from iPhone

Tags: iphone

I am developing an iPhone application which requires the sending of an "Secure SMS", i am able ot send the sms from within our application using MFMessageComposeViewController method, but i am not getting any help on how we can send an SMS securily like the text should be encrypted from client side(iPhone) and it should be decrypted at server side and also vice versa.

any sample code or ideas would be appreciated.

thanks
shiva.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://septicus.com/products/opensource/ is a valuable resource that let you use openSSL in Cocoa environment.

---

from main.m of SSCrypt framework

```
// generate a private key
NSData *privateKeyData = [SSCrypto generateRSAPrivateKeyWithLength:2048];
// generate a public key from the private key data
NSData *publicKeyData = [SSCrypto generateRSAPublicKeyFromPrivateKey:privateKeyData];
```

And

```
crypto = [[SSCrypto alloc] initWithPublicKey:publicKeyData privateKey:privateKeyData];

NSString *topSecret = @"Billy likes Mandy";
[crypto setClearTextWithString:topSecret];

NSData *encryptedTextData = [crypto encrypt];
NSData *decryptedTextData = [crypto decrypt];

NSLog(@"Top Secret: %@", topSecret);
NSLog(@"Encrypted: %@", [encryptedTextData encodeBase64]);
NSLog(@"Decrypted: %s", [decryptedTextData bytes]);

[crypto release];
```

Comment: To elaborate, create a public-private key pair and store the public key in senders. Using SSCrypto framework on the link I provided, RSA-encrypt a message using the public key. The reader requires the private key to read the message, and (s)he can also use SSCrypto framework to RSA-decrypt the message.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable suggestion MHC i will look into this.

Comment: I have downloaded the code from repositary and build it, and created a new project for iPhone, added SSCrypto.framework,Appkit.framework, and other 2 lib files and also SSCrypto.h and .m files also inclded in my project.When i give a build then i am getting 73 errors saying openssl/evp.h and other header files with openssl/ are undeclared. how can i resolve these errors MHC.

Comment: It seems like you need add header file path for your project. Go to your build settings and search for headers folder path.

Comment: Ok thnak you very much MHC for quick reply, I added all the header files and also included in header search paths now its working. but i am not understanding how actual encryption and decryption is happening. if you know can you please explain me.

Comment: main.m file in the framework shows an example of creating an RSA key pair and encrypt/decrypt using that.

Comment: For some reasons, I didn't realize your question is tagged `iPhone`. In this case, you may want to look at Yllier's porting of SSCrypto for iPhone.

Comment: Thank you MHC, I Tried that Yllier's site getting an error for establishing a database connection. i tagged iPhone because i need this "Secure SMS" to be send from iPhone.I have seen main.m file he is creating one public key and one private key and calling SSCrypto class for encrypting and decrypting there he is doing some algorithm to encrypt and decrypt, i didn't understand how he is generating publickey and private key and also algorithm used for encrypting and decrypting.if i am wrong any where please ignore it.thank you for your valuable suggestions once again.

Comment: Absolutely you wanted to send an SMS. Silly me. if you read the main.m file from the original framework (which is included in readme.txt in Yllier's porting), then you will find it from Test 3 and Test 4. I quoted them in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As for the question, your going to have to do the encryption on your own using most likely public/private key encryption, such as RSA.

Answer (score 0):

There's absolutely no way for you to control what happens to the SMS data you send after you dismiss `MFMessageComposeViewController`. Once it's sent, the receiver will simply receive the SMS message, and no app can control what else happens.

Comment: Well you can send encrypted messages (pure text) over SMS and let the receiver decrypt them. Security need not rely on the SMS layer.

Comment: Right, but my perception of the question is that he's looking to have SMS encrypted and decrypted by the receiver, the iPhone app. The iPhone won't let you do anything special with SMS messages you receive, so it would just display the encrypted message from the server.